# pyautogui live image locator

Tags: python, pyautogui

i've got a problem in python :

```
import pyautogui as a
while True:
    pixel = a.locateOnScreen("example.png")
    if pixel == None: continue
    pixel = a.center(pixel)
    data = [pixel.x , pixel.y]
    a.moveTo(data[0],data[1])
```

in this code it finds the picture and move the mouse on it but its to slow because every time loop start from beginning it loads the file and it makes it too slow.
i want it to work lively.
i tried:

```
import pyautogui as a
from IPython.display import Image
f = Image("example.png")
while True:
    pixel = a.locateOnScreen(f)
    pixel = a.center(pixel)
    data = [pixel.x , pixel.y]
    a.moveTo(data[0],data[1])
```

but it says image don't have attribute named mode

I want to place pointer on the center of picture

Answer (score 0):

You use `IPython.display.Image` object, but that is the wrong one. Use `PIL.Image` instead:

```
import pyautogui as a
from PIL import Image
f = Image.open("example.png")
while True:
    pixel = a.locateOnScreen(f)
    pixel = a.center(pixel)
    data = [pixel.x , pixel.y]
    a.moveTo(data[0],data[1])
```

I confirmed this works with pyautogui version 0.9.53

That said, I don't think that the loading of the image is your performance bottleneck here, but rather the search algorithm itself. Pyautogui's [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions) states that `locateOnScreen` can take some time. You can try to search a smaller region on the screen. Citing:

> These “locate” functions are fairly expensive; they can take a full
> second to run. The best way to speed them up is to pass a region
> argument (a 4-integer tuple of (left, top, width, height)) to only
> search a smaller region of the screen instead of the full screen:
>
> ```
> import pyautogui
> pyautogui.locateOnScreen('someButton.png', region=(0,0, 300, 400))
> ```